# Why is a 2-electron wavefunction antisymmetric?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, pauli-exclusion-principle, identical-particles

Why does a 2-electron system have an antisymmetric wavefunction when the combination should be bosonic? I.e. If it's an overall bosonic combination, shouldn't the overall wavefunction be symmetric?

Comment: Why do you think the overall combination should be bosonic?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can be easily resolved by consulting a textbook.

Comment: Because the total spin of a 2-electron system is 1, a boson. So I figure the wavefunction that describes this system should be symmetric.

Comment: Vadim, that's ridiculous! Can't one say that about nearly every post in the "homework" tags? Clearly, I read a *&^% text and don't understand why.

Comment: @AspiringPhysicist Note that if you want to respond to a particular comment then please add the members ID (like I did here) so they get notified of a comment for their attention.  They may not see it otherwise.  The person who made the original post gets automatically notified, so no need to let them know normal (kust done as an example here).

Comment: @AspiringPhysicist if you believe that your question is a valid one, perhaps you should expand it to make it clearer - the answer may actually come naturally when  thinking it over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

States of a system of indistinguishable fermions are antisymmetric under exchange of any two particles. This is the defining characteristic of what it means to be a fermion.

Of course, this means that they're symmetric under the exchange of any two *pairs* of particles.  If you have e.g. two hydrogen atoms in your system, then exchanging the electronic states gives you a minus sign which is canceled out by exchanging the proton states.  In that sense, the state of such a system is symmetric under exchange of *hydrogen atoms* (proton+electron pairs), but antisymmetric under either exchange individually.

Comment: Thank you! This clears it up. So, the antisymmetric w.f. looks at the constituent particle while a symmetric w.f. looks at the composite particle. Thanks again for clearing that up!

Comment: @AspiringPhysicist Yes, but be careful.  The wavefunction of a system of two hydrogen atoms is a function of four (vector) variables - the positions of the protons $x_p,y_p$ and the electrons $x_e,y_e$.  The fermionic nature of protons and electrons means that $\psi(x_p,x_e,y_p,y_e)=-\psi(x_p,y_e,y_p,x_e)=-\psi(y_p,x_e,x_p,y_e)$, but of course that implies that $\psi(x_p,x_e,y_p,y_e)=\psi(y_p,y_e,x_p,x_e)$.

Comment: And of course, the $\psi$ I mentioned is really a spatial wavefunction multiplied by four 2-component spinors, so everything gets some added complexity there.

Comment: Thank you. That really clears this up... I need to remember to be very careful when exchanging fermions!